# how to decrease the legend width in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using the matlab to plot some project figures, see the blow figure. Now I am trying to cut the legend width so that the line won't look so wide. I tried these command as suggest by Benoit_11:

```
[~,icons,~,~] = legend(leg,'location','northwest');
hline = icons(2);
linedata = get(hline,'xdata');
newdata = [linedata(1)+0.2 linedata(2)];
set(hline,'xdata',newdata,'linewidth',1)
```

I am using the for loop to plot these figures because I have multiple figures to analysis at the same time. Now I can change the length of the legend line right now. But I got another problem: if I have different length of legend text, even if I set the same starting point and end point, I will get different length for the line in the end (you can see that from the figures). I tried to modify icon(1) but always got the error. Any suggestions?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 things you are not doing right with your code (aside the fact that you use `size` as the handles to the legend...that's risky because `size` is a built-in function):

1)  Calling `legend` with only 1 argument returns a handle to the legend object and getting its position actually gives you the position of the box enclosing the legend, i.e. the text + the line.

2) Using this line:

```
p(3) = p(3) - 0.06;
```

does modify the position, however you would need to set the new position of the legend with something like the following for the changes to be effective:

```
set(HandleToLegend,'Position',p)
```

To come back to your question, the trick is to assign many outputs during the call to `legend`; you can then modify specific elements of the legend object.

Actually we only need 1 of the 4 output arguments, called `icons` in the docs so I'll stick with the notation. Then, we can get the `XData` property of the line and modify it as we want. The `XData` is actually a 2-element vector:

```
[StartingPoint EndingPoint]
```

so changing one or the other (or both)  will change the length of the line displayed in the legend box.

Here is the whole code with comments; I changed the length and linewidth of the line in the 2nd plot to highlight the changes.

```
clear
clc
close all
x = 1:10;
y = rand(1,10);
figure;

%// Default case
subplot(1,2,1)
plot(x,y);

legend('First plot','Location','NorthWest');

title('Before','FontSize',18);

%// With modifications
subplot(1,2,2)
plot(x,y);
title('After','FontSize',18);

%//========================
%// Change the legend here
%//========================

%// The "icons" output is what you want
[~,icons,~,~] = legend('First plot','Location','NorthWest');

%// icons(1) is the text of the current element in the legend Here its 'First plot'
i_1 = get(icons(1)); %// access the properties with this command.

%// icons(2) is the line associated with that text. Here the blue line.
i_2 = get(icons(2));

%// Mhh I don't know what icons(3) represents haha sorry about that.
i_3 = get(icons(3));


%// Get the actual line
hline = icons(2);

%// Fetch its XData property
LineData = get(hline,'XData')

%// Play with those 2 elements to see the output change.
NewData = [LineData(1)+.2 LineData(2)-.01];

%// Apply the changes
set(hline,'XData',NewData,'LineWidth',3)
```

Which gives the following:

[image]

Comment: This works like a magic. Also, there is a way to also make the text closer to the shortened line?

Comment: Also, why you selected the 2nd element for the {icon}? I changed it to the 1st and 3rd element, but got the error. I am trying to understand your magic code.

Comment: haha sorry about that it was late yesterday I thought I had explained better :) Please look at the edited answer I hope its clearer now.

Comment: I played with the 2 elements in the linedata and I can change the length of the legend line right now. But I got another problem: if I have different length of legend text, even if I set the same starting point and end point, I will get different length for the line in the end. I tried to modify icon(1) but always got the error.

Answer (score -1):

You need to set the value of the `Position` property, you can just change the vector `p`. `p` does not affect the plot at all, it's just a vector of numbers. You have to modify it, then apply it back to the plot, using

```
set(size,'Position',p)
```

There does seem to be a minimum width of the legend however.